# Dynamic environment URL

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, dotenv

I saw on the gitlab documentation (*https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments.html#set-dynamic-environment-urls-after-a-job-finishes*) that we can use a dynamic url by using artifacts:reports:dotenv so I tried to generate a random port under script, then i store that port under a variable and I use it the environment url (it is quite similar to the example provided in the documentation). But the pipeline failed and I got yaml error with the following message error: "artifacts:reports config contain unknown keys: dotenv".

It seems that I should install dotenv(*https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv*) but where should I do this installation ? maybe on the gitlab host ? or how it could be resolved ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unknown keys: dotenv` suggests that this is not supported in your installation of GitLab.

Docs you mentioned says `Introduced in GitLab 12.9.`.

What is your GitLab version? Version can be checked by going to `<gitlab url>/help`.